# Solving unorderable types: str() > int() exception

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a simple function that takes in a list of integers, and returns the sum of all prime numbers in the array.
This is my code so far:

```
def sum_of_primes(n):
    try:
        n == list
    except ValueError:
        return 'Invalid Argument'
    sum = 0
    fact = []

    for i in range(0, len(n)):
        num = n[i]
        if num > 1:
            fact = []
            for j in range (1, num+1):
                if num % j == 0:
                    fact += [j]
        if fact == [1, num]:
            sum = sum + num
```

But I keep getting this error.

```
Unhandled Exception: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: what is `n == list` supposed to do? You are comparing what is presumably a list of integers with a built-in class. That really makes very little sense. A list of integers is not equal to a built-in class, and having it in a `try-except` block like that is odd. I think you need `isinstance()`

Comment: @JohnColeman Well I am new to python, and ''All invalid inputs should return the string: 'Invalid Argument''' was part of my instructions.

Comment: In any event, the error probably comes from you passing your function a list of strings that haven't been converted to integers. You should say what line is throwing the error, but my guess is that it is `num > i`

Comment: @JohnColeman It is the 'num > 1' line. How do I resolve it?

Comment: As @Unlocked pointed out -- you are passing lists which contain strings to your function. You should really give a [mcve] if you want an optimal amount of help. Show the relevant calling code. My guess is that you are using `input()` (or `raw_input()` if this is Python 2) to get input from the user but you are not using `int()` to convert that input to integers.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is not a list of integers, or at least not entirely. There is a string somewhere in `n`, which throws an error when it's compared to 1.

Also, `n == list` will never throw an error, and will always return `False`. What you want is `if type(n) == list`, or more preferably, `if isinstance(n, list)`.